# Create View and show tax terms that use the same term as the content

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

everyone,

I am currently trying to create a view, but unfortunately I can't get a result.

Initial situation:

ContentType A uses a term from Tax B
Tax C uses a term from Tax B

Now I would like to have all terms of C listed on the page of A, which have the same tax term of B as A.

Example:
A= content of the topic "software"

Tax B = various industries (software, consulting, finance, construction, medicine....)

A has the term "software" from Tax B

Tax C = Various companies

C also has a term from Tax B, e. g. Microsoft is assigned to "software".

Now I would like to list beside the article about software all companies, which have also assigned the term "software".

What I've done so far:
1) View created as a block, output of taxonomy terms of vocabulary C (company)
2.) Taxonomy Term field: Name added to output
3.) Context filter taxonomy term:  (B) added
If the filter value is NOT available: Provide default value: Taxonomy term ID from URL
[x] Load standard filter of the term page
[x] Load default filter of the node page (good for related vocabulary blocks).
------[x]Industry

If I test the view in the preview with a TID from Tax B, then it works, too. But unfortunately not on the website.

Can you help me with that? I would appreciate a helpful answer!

Greetings,
Alex

Comment: Are you placing the view on a node or taxonomy term page? Sounds like you are doing something similar to http://redcrackle.com/blog/adding-contextual-filter-view-drupal-8

Answer (score 0):

It works in your test because you're giving it a TID, but in actual practice, that won't be in the URL when you're viewing the content. Therefore, your contextual filter shouldn't be a taxonomy term, but the content ID from the URL, use that to get the node's taxonomy terms (B), and then you might be able to directly get other items, filtered as taxonomy terms (C) that share those, or else you might need to use relationships.